# Why is the live wire reading live, but the neutral is not, in my lighting circuit?

Tags: electrical, wiring, lighting

A ceiling light has failed and I have removed it.  The circuit that it was part of (eight other downstairs lights) is working fine. BUT the supply cable from this circuit to the failed light is 'live' for the live wire but not 'live' for the neutral.  So my replacement light fitting is not working. Where can the problem be?

Answer (score 2):

> **Where can the problem be?**

The problem might be that you didn't take into account that neutral is usually tied to ground/earth. In the US this typically occurs at the point the supply enters the building.